# Why is checking closed subscheme a local problem

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the proof of Proposition 5.9 (page 116) of Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*, he wrote

> ... we only have to check that $(Y, \mathscr{O}_X/\mathscr{I})$ is a closed subscheme [of X]. This is a **local question**, so we may assume $X = \text{Spec }A$ is affine.

I wonder what he meant by that. Is it true that $f : Y \rightarrow X$ is a closed immersion if and only if for any open affine cover $U_i$ of $X$, $f : f^{-1}(U_i) \rightarrow X$ is closed immersion?

**EDIT**: I just realize that this is true.

Comment: The point-set topology part is done [in this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3145/is-whether-a-set-is-closed-or-not-a-local-property).

Comment: The algebraic part is done here:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1570581/fx-rightarrow-y-is-a-closed-immersion-iff-ff-1u-i-rightarrow-u-i-is-a/1570605#1570605