# Multiplicity of Cartier divisor on locally noetherian scheme is only non-zero at generic point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I'm following chapter 7 in Qing Liu's book 'Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves' about 'Divisors and applications to curves'.

My question concerns Definition 1.27:

> Let $A$ be a Noetherian local ring of dimension 1. For any regular element $\ f \in A, \text{length}_A(A/fA)$ is finite. The map $f \mapsto \text{length}_A(A/fA)$ extends to a group homomorphism $\text{Frac}(A)^\times \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$. Moreover, its kernel contains the invertible elements of $A$. Thus we obtain a group homomorphism $\text{mult}_A:\text{Frac}(A)^\times/A^\times \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$.

This map will be used to define $\text{mult}_x(D)$ of a Cartier Divisor $D$ at a point $x \in X$:

> Let $X$ be a locally Noetherian scheme. Let $D \in \text{Div}(X)$ be a Cartier divisor. For any point $x \in X$ of codimension 1, the stalk of $D$ at $x$ belongs to $$(\mathcal{K}_X^\times/\mathcal{O}_X^\times)_x = \text{Frac}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})^\times/\mathcal{O}_{X,x}^\times,$$ thus we can define $$\text{mult}_x(D) := \text{mult}_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}(D).$$ Now let $U$ be an open everywhere dense (does this simply mean *dense*?) subset of $X$ such that $D_U = 0.$ **Then:** Any $x \in X$ of codimension 1 such that $\text{mult}_x(D) \neq 0$ is a generic point of $X-U$.

**My Question:** Why does the last statement hold?

The result seems to be very important and fundemanetal (hence the question), since following the statement, a Cartier divisor is determined on the generic points of $X$. Further, for assigning Weil divisors to Cartier divisors, we need that there are only finitely many prime divisors at which the Cartier divisor is non-zero - which is (with the above) a consequence if $X$ is assumed to be Noetherian.

I would be very grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: I don't know the exact answer to your question right away, but I note one red flag: the highlighted text talks about generic points of $X-U$, but you talk about generic points of $X$. These are very different things!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $D_U=0$ shows that multiplicity non-zero in particular implies $x \in X-U$, hence the closure of $x$ is contained in $X-U$ and has the same dimension by assumption. ($X-U$ having codimension at least $1$ is the everywhere dense condition)

---

Here is a rigorous proof using your definitions.

Let $x$ be a point with multiplicity non-zero. As I stated above, $D_U=0$ implies $x \in X-U$.

Let $y \in X-U$ with $x \in \overline {\{y\}}$. We have to show $x=y$, which is equivalent to $\overline {\{x\}}=\overline {\{y\}}$ (This equivalence essentially uses, that we work with a scheme. On arbitrary topological spaces, this is of course wrong).

Assume this does not hold, then we have $\overline {\{x\}} \subsetneq \overline {\{y\}}$. By the co-dimension $1$ assumption for $x$, we get that $\overline {\{y\}}$ is a maximal irreducible subset of $X$. Note that $\overline {\{y\}} \subset X-U$, since $y \in X-U$.

Now let $\mathcal Z$ be the set of maximal irreducible closed subsets of $X$. I claim that $S = \bigcup\limits_{Z \in \mathcal Z, Z \neq \overline {\{y\}}} Z$ is a closed subset. In particular it is a proper closed subset (it does not contain $y$), which contains $U$. This is a contradiction to the assumption that $U$ is dense.

To proof my claim, I will proof the following lemma:

> Let $X$ be a locally noetherian scheme and $Z_i, i \in I$ a collection
>   of maximal irreducible closed subsets. Then their union is a closed
>   set. (Note that infinite unions are not closed in general)

*Proof:* Let $U$ be an open affine subset. By the locally noetherian assumption, $U$ is noetherian. For any $i$ $U \cap Z_i$ is an irreducible subset of $U$. By the noetherian property, the union $\bigcup_{i \in I} U \cap Z_i$ is actually a *finite* union, i.e. closed. Since we can cover $X$ be such $U$'s and we can [test being closed on an open cover](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3145/is-whether-a-set-is-closed-or-not-a-local-property), the result follows.

---

You should note that the proof becomes **essentially easier**, when one assumes $X$ to be noetherian, because we have finitely many irreducible components then and thus can immediately derive that $\overline {\{x\}}$ is an irreducible component of $X-U$, which is equivalent to be *a generic point*.

Comment: So, $U \subset X$ **everywhere dense** $\Leftrightarrow\ \text{codim}_X(X-U) \geq 1$?

Comment: Only the forward direction is true (Think of the union of a curve and an isolated closed point. Take the open subset to be the curve). If all irreducible components have the same dimension, then the equivalence holds.

Comment: Then, would you mind telling me what the definition of **everywhere dense** is? What is the difference to just **dense**?
Because this would imply that for any $x \in X-U$ we have $\text{codim}_X \{x\}^- \geq 1$. This should further imply (how?) that if the codimension of such $x$ is exactly 1, that $\{x\}^- = X-U$, right?

Comment: It is the same as dense. Meaning that $U$ does not leave out an irreducible component.

Comment: Do we have to worry about the underlying space being not necessarily noetherian?

Comment: @MooS Could you give me the proof or the reference for the statement that if now $x$ and $X-U$ having the same (co)dimension (?) it follows $\{x\}^- = X-U$?

Comment: This does not hold of course, since $X-U$ might not be irreducible. You should look up what the author means with '*a* generic point'. I guess he means that it is the generic point of an irreducible component.

Comment: @MooS Liu defines a generic point $x \in X$ to be a point with the property: For any $y \in X $, $x \notin \{y\}^-$ unless $x=y $. From this he deduces that there is a 1to1 correspondence between generic points of $X $ and the irreducible components of $X $. One direction of this correspondence is given by taking the closure.

Comment: Ok, finally you gave us some precise definition. I will edit my answer to give a rigorous proof.

Comment: @Hoot Actually you were right, we have to worry about the missing noetherian assumption. The proof becomes more technical without it, I have edited my answer.

Comment: @ MooS Thank you very much for this rigorous proof. And I'm sorry for being that late giving the precise definition of *a generic point*.