# Only finite many multiplicities of Cartier divisor are non zero

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I am trying to understand the multiplicities of Cartier divisors in Liu’s book on the relevant chapter. Actually I cannot understand the following conclusion of this remark.

Now let $ $ be an open everywhere dense subset of $$ such that $_{}=0$.
Then: Any $∈$ of codimension 1 such that $mult()≠0$ is a generic point of $−. $

THEN: The above implies that in an open affine subset of $X$, there are only finite many codimension 1 points such that the corresponding multiplicity are non-zero. I’ve seen
[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859320/multiplicity-of-cartier-divisor-on-locally-noetherian-scheme-is-only-non-zero-at#comment3807454_1859396) but I really need to understand the full conclusion, namely the last statement.

Comment: You need to provide more background here: what specific place in Liu's book is this from? What assumptions are involved here? What is $X$, specifically? Next, you probably have a typo in the last paragraph: you want "only finitely many codimension 1 points such that the corresponding multiplicity is ***non-zero***", not zero as currently said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i found out. We restrict to an open affine $V$ and the closure of the intersection $U\cap V$ in $V$ is $V$. Hence we can apply the first claim, since the affine $V$ is noetherian and hence has finitely many irreducible components.